# Rename multiple files on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, batch-rename

I have files with *standarized* names like:

```
img_db_DD-MM-YYYY.dat
```

So I want to rename them to this:

```
img_db_YYYY-MM-DD.dat
```

How can I achieve that? I have seen how to rename multiple files with CMD but I don't know how to do this particular case.

Comment: Have you looked into tools like [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/)?

Comment: We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that in Windows explorer. The two options are:

1. Use Powershell. This will require programming though.
2. Use Bulk Rename Tool, http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php Its completely free and can make the changes you're looking at.

Comment: Despite I needed to do this using Windows built-in tools (unfortunatelly I don't have experience with Powershell), this is something that really helps. Thank you, @Ishan!

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a file with extension .ps1

2) Copy my code into this file

3) Modify my code for set $yourdirectory with your directory.

4) right click on this file, run with PowerShell

```
   $yourdirectory="C:\temp\"

   $listfile=gci -Path $yourdirectory -File -Filter "*.dat" | Where-Object{$_ -match "img_db_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.dat"}     

   foreach ($file in $listfile)
   {

   [int[]] $stringsplit=($file.Name.Substring(7, 10)) -split "-"

   $madate=(new-object System.DateTime $stringsplit[2], $stringsplit[1], $stringsplit[0])
   $newstring=$file.DirectoryName + "\img_db_" + $madate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".dat"

   Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName $newstring


   }
```